# How do I get the Flyway version number of a database

Tags: jenkins, flyway

I want to pull out the pre-deployment Flyway version number of my production database so I can use this in my continuous deployment pipeline (Jenkins) in case I do a rollback later.

How can I achieve this?

One option would be to query the flyway history table, but I can't work out a fail-safe way of achieving this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? `flyway info` maybe?

Comment: I've tried all the command line parameters. Info is where I'd have expected to find it, but all this does is show the available migrations. It does show version numbers, and technically it's possible to work out by mentally parsing the table, but not fit for purpose to fetch the value programmatically.

Comment: I agree that it could be easier, but as long as you don't allow out-of-order migrations, then it should be the last line with state success, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, so I thought until I started using undo migrations, which muddles the table to the extent that it's hard to get the information I need. Interestingly there are some commands (like undo and migrate) that reveal the version. The trouble is that I don't want to execute these commands. I just want the version. I guess this might end up being a feature request for the info command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fashioned an answer, although it feels like a big of a hack. I run --dryRunOutput in migrate as a means to get flyway to output the version number to the screen, as info doesn't do this for some reason.

I read the output into a file (because DOS makes it hard to pipe or pass into a variable) then isolate the output line starting with "Current". I then pick the second token using : as my delimeter. There's probably an easier way, and I wish I could use flyway info instead of migrate as my method feels hacky, but at least it works for now.

```
flyway -dryRunOutput=test.sql migrate | FIND "Current" >currentversion.txt
for /f "delims=" %%x in (currentversion.txt) do set CURRENTVERSIONLINE=%%x
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ("%CURRENTVERSIONLINE%") do set CURRENTVERSION=%%b
echo Version  : %CURRENTVERSION%
```

Answer (score 0):

The following one-liner does what you want:

`flyway info | grep Success | tail -1 | cut -f3 "-d|" | xargs`

Comment: Not sure this works if I have completed ("Success") Undos in there does it, as it will pick up this line instead.

Comment: It's the undo scripts that are marked as Success that cause the false positives, not the Undones.